# How to use django-sitetree? 2.0

Tags: django, navigation, sitemap, breadcrumbs

I have annoying problems using [django-sitetree](https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree) (version 0.5.1) for generating a navigation menu with Django. For testing purposes I tried to configure django-sitetree to make a sitetree for the "Polls" app ([official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)). I configured it according to [some instructions answering a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766807/how-to-use-django-sitetree) - but i ran into trouble using url patterns, which didn't work for me.

So these are my url patterns for "Polls", which are included in /polls (I don't use trailing slashes):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^/(?P<poll_id>\d+)$', 'detail'),
    (r'^/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results$', 'results'),
    (r'^/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote$', 'vote'),
)
```

I only configured the views `index` and `detail` like this via Django admin:

```
Title                        URL
My site                      /
+ Polls                      polls.views.index
  + Poll {{ poll.question }  polls.views.detail poll.id
```

Which produces the following output using `{% sitetree_menu from "maintree" include "trunk" %}` on my main page `/`

```
Title                        URL
My site                      /
+ Polls                      /polls
  + Poll                     #unresolved
```

But what I am *expecting* is:

```
Title                        URL
My site                      /
+ Polls                      /polls
  + Poll foo                 /polls/1
  + Poll Test #2             /polls/2
```

I have already tried several things like using named views in the urls.py (as recommended in the documentation), but i don't even get a simple `{% sitetree_url %}` working with parameters. It's a pity to see that there's nothing helpful on the web except some copies of the answer mentioned above. I would appreciate it if anyone helped me out with a more detailed one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way for the application to meet your expectations, i.e. it can't figure out how many polls you have described by "Poll {{ poll.question }" of yours, and which of them you want to show in the menu.

I should try to think this feature over, but frankly speaking, I do not consider placing dozens of polls in the menu a good idea.

Nevertheless, there are several ways you can cope with it:

1. Create entries for each poll you need manually;
2. Add poll entry to the tree when new poll is created, e.g. using signals and model's API. As you can see, it is the same as option 1, but automatized;
3. Do not show "Poll {{ poll.question }" in the menu and sitetree, but only in breadcrumbs. Thus considering "Polls" page for navigation through polls list. In case of breadcrumbs "Poll {{ poll.question }" will be resolved into full title when on pool's page according to given rules.

---

For *hardyharzen*, who asks in the comments for an example on no.2:

- You can read about signals at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/.
- Django built-in signals we will use are described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/.

Suppose we are still talking about polls. Put the following code in polls app models.py file.

*Note that this code adds tree item into site tree with id 1, at tree branch with id 10, and expects Poll model to have get_absolute_url() method defined.*

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save  
from django.dispatch import receiver  
from sitetree.models import TreeItem
```

-

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Poll)
def on_poll_add(instance, created, **kwargs)
    if created:
        tree_item = TreeItem(title=instance.title, tree_id=1, 
            parent_id=10, url=instance.get_absolute_url())  
        tree_item.save(force_insert=True)
```

Comment: [django-newbie-speaking]: Would you please elaborate on 2.? This sounds like an elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I already figured out using the Poll in the menu or sitetree isn't really smart, and using the breadcrumbs navigation works just well. I don't think one needs to do things as I tried often.

Comment: I have a few minor questions: Is there any way to limit the nesting depth to a given number when using a sitetree or a menu? And if I use the breadcrumbs in my base template, I always get a TemplateError when extending it with an app for which no treeItem is defined. How to avoid this? It would be fine if you could make an exception using a boolean like treeitem_available in the template.

Comment: @purefanatic You can override built-in templates to limit the depth of rendered tree. 
To avoid TemplateErrors you can wrap `sitetree_breadcrumbs` tag in `block` tag, that for your app with no tree items defined you can replace with empty `block` tag. That is really a matter of templates juggling.

Comment: As you can see, I don't have much experience with Django. I am trying to learn more about it. Thank you again for helping out!